# Applying annotations to map kit

Tags: ios, annotations, storyboard, mkmapview

My problem is that I cannot find any up to date tutorials with iOS6 and map kit that include storyboards instructing you on how to apply annotations/pins  with the use of for-ordinates.

My homework tells me that the tutorials out there are xib, iOS 5 related which now defeats the point because apple implemented their own maps with ios6 and are no longer using Google's..

I've used google and checked out apple's developer's guide..

I can't be the only one searching for this answer...?

Many thanks.

Comment: It is better not to mention the forbidden word 'homework' in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MapKit API is essentially same between iOS5 and iOS6 - what changed was the source of the mapping data, the graphic design of the maps, and the use of vector data over bitmap data. But most of this is opaque at the API level. Between iOS versions you continue to use the same framework and classes. There are a few additions (such as MKMapItem, routing) and a few simplifications, but any code written for Apple's iOS5 MapKit SDK will work with iOS6 MapKit.

Issues of xib vs. storyboard tutorials are not specific to MapKit, and nothing in MapKit relies on one or the other, so you shouldn't allow that to confuse you. However, here is an iOS6 tutorial to get you started:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

For an overview of changes between ios5 and ios6 MapsKit, take a look at the WWDC video from 2012,[Getting Around Using Map Kit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=300).

Answer (score 0):

so by using the code below, I've manage to place one pin by using coordinates and placing it in viewDidLoad, but when the code is copied, it fails to build. Any solutions for adding multiple co-ordinates?

Comment: KPointAnnotation *annot = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; annot.title = @"Title"; annot.subtitle = @"title"; annot.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.138737, -0.471611) ; [_mapView addAnnotation:annot]

Comment: You should edit your Question with this code and info (it's not an Answer).  Since you've already Accepted an Answer to the original Question, you may want to post this as a new Question.  In addition, it's important to specify exactly what errors or messages you get and on what line when "it fails to build".  Also, what is the exact difficulty you're having adding multiple annotations?  How many annotations?  Will they be static or come dynamically from a server, etc...